# C# comparing two strings letter by letter and storing the results to an array

Tags: c#-4.0

What Im trying to do is after checking if correct I want to count the number of correct answers for each question, ans is the master key consisting of 20 questions.  the Answer key looks like this "ABBBCAADEAAECABBCABB" and is read from a .txt file. so for example question 1: 10 correct responses, question 2: 5 correct.

```
               string answers = Convert.ToString(token[1]);
                for (var x = 0; x < answers.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (ans[x] == answers[x])
                    {
                        score = score + 4;
                    }
                    else if (answers[x] == 'X')
                    {
                        score = score;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        score = score - 4;
                    }

                }
```

Comment: What does answers[x] == 'X' mean? That there is no answer? What do you mean by score = score - +0; ? (the -+ part) 
Also, what is the problem?

Comment: answer[x]=='X' means if they write X for an answer the score doesnt change. so if you wrote X 20 times you would get a score of 0 exited the -+ just put score= score;

Comment: What is your problem, then? Do you have an matrix at ans? You are not clear what you want to do

Comment: my apologies,  ans is my answer key it stores a string that read BECDCBAADEBACBEDDBED what I need to do is when an answer is correct i want to count how many were correct for each question.

Comment: No its not a matrix. I will try that, Im new to c# few months, I just read up on matrix after you mentioned it. thank you for your help

Comment: If you say for each question, it means that you have an array/list of answers from different students? Possible in token?

Comment: yes I have it inside a while loop currently so the token checks each students answer

Comment: ok. Create an int[] with length answer.length, that will contain the number of correct answers for each question. Create this outside the while loop.
Inside the while loop, but outside the for loop, initialise the elemnt of the array to 0. Then inside the if (ans[x] == answers[x])
                    {
                        score = score + 4;
                    }
increment that value. 
Notes: You may want to change token[1] to token[i] where i is the index of student.
Also the else if is useless

Answer (score 0):

From what you specified in the comments:
Create an `int[]` with length `answer.length`, that will contain the number of correct answers for each question. Create this outside the while loop.

Inside the `while` loop, but outside the `for` loop, initialize the element of the array to 0.

Then inside the `if (ans[x] == answers[x]) { score = score + 4; }` increment that value.

Notes: You may want to change `token[1]` to `token[i]` where `i` is the index of student. Also the  `score = score;` inside `else if` is useless. Change

```
else if (answers[x] == 'X')
        {
            score = score;
        }
else
      {
            score = score - 4;
      }
```

to:

```
else if (answers[x] != 'X')
        {
            score = score - 4;
        }
```